# Power BI Tooltip Toggle On w/ Deneb Custom Visual

Tags: powerbi, tooltip, toggle, powerbi-custom-visuals, deneb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPVuu.png)
I want the tooltip to be toggled on inside of my deneb custom visual instead of a mouse hover option. The reason is that I have a link I can't click inside of the tooltip because when I move my cursor away, the tooltip goes away.

Here is the tooltip Vega-Lite/JSON code:
I want to be able to click that MS Issue Link inside of my visual

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0vDe.png)

I've tried specific commands to toggle the tooltip but it just erases the model due to code errors